# Composite Mappings and the Adjoint of a Linear Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a mapping (over a field F),

$T: U \rightarrow V$ and a mapping $S: V \rightarrow   W$ .

Then I want to show that $(ST)' = T'S'$ where

$T'g$ is the adjoint for some linear form $g: U \rightarrow F$, and

$S'k$ is the adjoint of S for some linear form $k: W\rightarrow F$

I am confused what $T'S'$ will look like. Is it $T'(k \circ S)$? Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^{\prime}:V^*\to U^*$ is the map defined by
$$ (T^{\prime}f)(u)=f(Tu) $$
and similarly for $S^{\prime}$ and $(ST)^{\prime}$. Therefore
$$ ((ST)^{\prime}g)(u)=g(STu)=(S^{\prime}g)(Tu)=(T^{\prime}(S^{\prime}g))(u)$$
for all $g\in W^*$ and $u\in U$, hence $(ST)^{\prime}=T^{\prime}S^{\prime}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly $f$ is in both cases?

Comment: In the first line, $f$ is an element of $V^*$, i.e. a linear functional $V\to F$. In the second line, $f$ is an element of $W^*$. I think I will change the second one to $g$ to make it more clear.